# StAX Parsing - where to keep element schemas?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, configuration, stax

I need to write a parser to save data from XML in the format:

```
<!-- Sample XML>
<Results>
    <TableA>
        <ID>7</ID>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
    </TableA>
    <TableA>
        <ID>8</ID>
        <Name>John</Name>
    </TableA>
</Results>
```

Into a `Map<String, Object>[]`.  Each TableA element will be one map of name/value pairs.

I'll have a great number of different tables this has to work for, each having its own schema with different name/value pairs, but the same layout.  I don't plan to mix results from different tables - I just want a generic way of loading the schema and parsing the similar documents.

**So, what's the best way to store/make use of the schemas in Java?**  I'm still reasonably new to it and don't know the conventions well yet.  I obviously don't want to hard code them.  Is Spring the best option or are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer after 17 days, so writing what my solution ended up being:

We stored the schemas in spring as maps, and loaded the beans directly to use in the parser.  It seems to work fairly well and be reasonably flexible.